# ArrayList with Custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, arraylist

So I am trying to follow the tutorial [here](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429) But instead of using an array to store the data like they did here:

```
Weather weather_data[] = new Weather[]
    {
        new Weather(R.drawable.weather_cloudy, "Cloudy"),
        new Weather(R.drawable.weather_showers, "Showers"),
        new Weather(R.drawable.weather_snow, "Snow"),
        new Weather(R.drawable.weather_storm, "Storm"),
        new Weather(R.drawable.weather_sunny, "Sunny")
    };
```

I want to use an arraylist like

```
ArrayList<Weather> weather_data = new ArrayList<Weather>();
```

and then store things as

```
weather_data.add(new new Weather(R.drawable.weather_cloudy, "Cloudy"));
```

But how would I go about changing

```
public class WeatherAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Weather>{

Context context;
int layoutResourceId;   
Weather data[] = null;

public WeatherAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Weather[] data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    WeatherHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new WeatherHolder();
        holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (WeatherHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    Weather weather = data[position];
    holder.txtTitle.setText(weather.title);
    holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(weather.icon);

    return row;
}

static class WeatherHolder
{
    ImageView imgIcon;
    TextView txtTitle;
}
}
```

To work with arraylist instead of just an array.

Thank you in advance,

Tyler

EDIT1:
I've tried changing

```
ArrayList<AllList> data = null;
public WeatherAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Weather> data) {
super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
this.context = context;
this.data = data;
}
```

and

```
Weather weather = data.get(position);
```

and then when I try to view it in logcat like so:

Log.d("weather_data",weather_data.toString());

which shows

```
02-13 21:06:50.542: D/allList_data(6410): [com.skateconnect.AllList@4220ecc0]
```

Comment: so , what's the problem you face ?

Comment: I'm not too sure on how to change the public class weatheradapter to use arraylist instead of just an array. I tried changing a couple things and it does not crash but it also does not show what it is supposed to. I'm adding something else to the main post to help with what I've tried so far,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, in your constructor just change it to use the `ArrayList` from

```
public WeatherAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Weather[] data)
```

to

```
public WeatherAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Weather> data)
```

Then obviously you would instantiate your list to change from

```
 Weather data[] = null;
```

to

```
ArrayList<Weather> data = null;
```

Comment: Yup done that. But when I try it the list just shows up blank, see the edit in the main question to see what the logcat give me.

Comment: I don't see where you get `weather_data`... You can't just print the `ArrayList` in your logcat or you will get the `String` value of the `Object`. Try printing the firs element

Comment: How would I print the first element? (weather_data.get(0)).toString()?

Comment: If `weather_data` is an `ArrayList`, yes

Comment: I have it intialized as ArrayList<Weather> weather_data = new ArrayList<Weather>(); and then Log.d("weather_data",(weather_data.get(0)).toString()); and it still comes up as before.

Comment: You don't have any data in it. It's an empty `ArrayList` initialize it to your list

Comment: But it's not empty. I have got it to show up in the list now. But the image is not showing up. I am still getting the same output in the logcat though.

Comment: I have the icon set to show as R.drawable.ic_launcher but it doesnt show up.

Comment: Yes, sir. So if you can't figure it out then you will need to post the xml for your rows. I am going to sleep soon but I can look in the morning if you don't figure it out

Comment: Got it to show, it was how I had the xml set up for the imageview. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It will be the same way but instead of creating array you will create `ArratList<Weather>`

take look on this

```
public class WeatherAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Weather>{

Context context;
int layoutResourceId;   
//Weather data[] = null;
ArrayList<Weather> data = null ;

public WeatherAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Weather> data) {
super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
this.context = context;
this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View row = convertView;
WeatherHolder holder = null;

if(row == null)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
    row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

    holder = new WeatherHolder();
    holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
    holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

    row.setTag(holder);
}
else
{
    holder = (WeatherHolder)row.getTag();
}

Weather weather = data.get(position);
holder.txtTitle.setText(weather.title);
holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(weather.icon);

return row;
}
```

and you will send in constructor the `ArrayList<Weather>`

feed me back in any issue

Comment: It still doesnt, show anything in the list. It shows the row in the list but none of the text or image are in the list. just an empty row

Answer (score 1):

It's way change to arraylist, this code is work

```
ArrayList<Weather> weather_data = new ArrayList<Weather>();  

weather_data.add(new Weather(R.drawable.weather_cloudy, "Cloudy"));
weather_data.add(new Weather(R.drawable.weather_showers, "Showers"));
weather_data.add(new Weather(R.drawable.weather_snow, "Snow"));
weather_data.add(new Weather(R.drawable.weather_storm, "Storm"));
weather_data.add(new Weather(R.drawable.weather_sunny, "Sunny"));

public class WeatherAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Weather>{

Context context;
int layoutResourceId;   
ArrayList<Weather> data = null;

public WeatherAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Weather data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    WeatherHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new WeatherHolder();
        holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (WeatherHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    Weather weather = data.get(position);
    holder.txtTitle.setText(weather.title);
    holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(weather.icon);

    return row;
}

static class WeatherHolder
{
    ImageView imgIcon;
    TextView txtTitle;
}
}
```

Comment: No error. The image just doesn't show, everything else does though :D