# ArrayList method to populate ListView

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I'm struggling to understand what should I do, in order to fetch info from database and put it on a ListView. I already have an method from my database class which look up for the specific info. It should return all the columns of that row.

database method:

```
public List<alvara_db> getAlvaras(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    List<alvara_db> projects = new ArrayList<>(); //SELECT * FROM TABLE_ALVARA WHERE projetoid = ?
    String[] project = new String[]{String.valueOf(id_projeto)};

    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM alvara WHERE projetoid = ?", project);
    if (cur.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            alvara_db alvaras = new alvara_db();
            alvaras.setPlaca(cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("placa")));
            alvaras.setProj_exec(cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("proj_exec")));
            alvaras.setResp_tec(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("resp_tec")));
            alvaras.setParecer(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("parecer")));
            projects.add(alvaras);
        }while(cur.moveToNext());

        return projects;
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

This method is being called here (HIGHLIGHTED IN CODE):

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.detalhes_projeto);
    listView_projectDetails = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.detalhes);

    TextView textView_data = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView31);
    TextView textView_Proc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView33);
    TextView textView_Requer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView35);

    projeto_db db = new projeto_db(this);
    Bundle bun2 = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bun2 != null) {
        int position = bun2.getInt("position");

        id_projeto = db.getUserProjects().get(position).getProj_id();
        tipo_obra = db.getUserProjects().get(position).getTipo();
        textView_data.setText(db.getUserProjects().get(position).getData());
        textView_Proc.setText(db.getUserProjects().get(position).getProcesso());
        textView_Requer.setText(db.getUserProjects().get(position).getRequeren());

        ListAdapter adapterlist = null;
        if(tipo_obra == 1){ *****HERE*****
            adapterlist = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                    this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    db.getAlvaras()
            );

        }else{
            adapterlist = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                    this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    db.getHabiteses()
            );

        }
        listView_projectDetails.setAdapter(adapterlist); *****I SET THE INFO FROM THE ARRAY LIST HERE*****
    }

    Toolbar my_toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(my_toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.detalhes_projeto);
}
```

On screen, it returns me one position with the "name of my package, the class with getters/setters@something" while I wanted it to return all the info from columns of the row related to projetoid = project.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.relatoriodeobras, PID: 3160
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.relatoriodeobras/com.example.relatoriodeobras.detalhes_projeto}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
               Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
                  at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:303)
                  at android.widget.CursorAdapter.init(CursorAdapter.java:172)
                  at android.widget.CursorAdapter.<init>(CursorAdapter.java:120)
                  at android.widget.ResourceCursorAdapter.<init>(ResourceCursorAdapter.java:52)
                  at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.<init>(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:78)
                  at com.example.relatoriodeobras.detalhes_projeto.onCreate(detalhes_projeto.java:64)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: u mean the db is returning wrong value ??

Comment: with custom columns...other than Strings...you have to create your custom adapter

Comment: @HextechEnthusiast : Check below link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21769507/arraylist-with-custom-arrayadapter

Comment: Did you want use Custom adapter class?

Comment: @ik024 on screen, where the listView is located it shows "com.packagename.appname.alvara_db@3fcbe0cd" in one single position. this table has 4 columns and I wanted it to return the info within those 4 columns in 4 positions of listView

Comment: use `SimpleCursorAdapter`: you will get it done in just 5-8 lines of code

Comment: @pskink Thanks, I'll look into it.

Comment: @pskink should I use SimpleCursorAdapter where I'm calling db.getAlvaras()?

Comment: `db.getAlvaras()` should just return a `Cursor` that you use directly in `SCA` - see `SCA` constructor

Comment: @pskink So that means that I need to change my method to cursor? method name is ArrayList<alvara_db> getAlvaras() {}

Comment: yes, just return a `Cursor`, nothing more, `public Cursor getAlvaras() {...`

Comment: @pskink I changed from ArrayList to Cursor and returned the cursor within the database method. Now I'm getting and error. Please see edit.

Comment: Should I change * from rawQuery to the columns I want?

Comment: yes, and add `_id` column: if you dont have any `id` field use `ROWID as _id`

Comment: But why should I add _id column? I already have an id column int this table, which is primary key and autoincrement.

Comment: so use this field: `"select your_primary_key_id as _id, ... where ..."`, `SCA` needs `_id` column to work properly

Comment: It's not working. I did what you said but it gets me the same error.

Comment: Okay. It worked. It was accessing the other part of my If... Ah, it seems that I've found another issue.

Comment: @pskink detailing the project needs to know what type it was. I was getting type but forgot to set it on the database method. As for the SimpleCursorAdapter, it worked. It shows me the first column of that row. I'll look for how to show more columns using the simple cursor adapter. You can place it as answer. I'll mark it as so.

Comment: if you need for example 4 columns to be shown your `from` and `to` arrays should have 4 items

Comment: @pskink In this case type 1 project has 4 items. How should it look in TO arrays? android.R.id.text1, 2, 3 and 4?

Comment: then you need an xml layout that have 4 `TextView`s and you are passing their `id`s

Comment: @pskink I have other questions regarding the layout. Which are not related to this topic anymore. Should I create another question or may I message you directly?

Comment: open another question then